# Where to ask questions that are usually rejected on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I ask questions that aren't Stack Overflow questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8401/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-arent-stack-overflow-questions)

I realize this question itself might very well get rejected, however it might serve as a road sign for those whose questions repeatedly get rejected on SO. I believe there are legitimate questions that warrant further, more dynamic discussion and lead to grayer zones than those that are allowed on Stack Overflow. Where would be the best place(s) to ask broader more general questions on the related topics of programming, web development, etc.?

Answer (score 5):

> I believe there are legitimate questions that warrant further, more dynamic discussion and lead to grayer zones than those that are allowed on stackoverflow.

In general, Stack Exchange sites are not for *discussion*. While many SE sites allow more subjective questions than Stack Overflow, we don't allow completely open-ended discussion questions.

You haven't given any examples of questions, so I can't state whether any particular question would be welcome on an SE site or not. Without knowing more about what specifically you're wanting to ask, we can't adequately give an answer.

Answer (score 3):

If your question is a conceptual programming one (i.e. you are standing in front of your white board, rather than sitting in front of an IDE), you might try http://programmers.stackexchange.com.  But it's not "everything goes" over there; read their FAQ first.

For the record, web development questions are perfectly OK on Stack Overflow, but we don't answer *every* possible question that might be remotely related to software development.  For example, questions about Html and CSS are OK on Stack Overflow, as are questions related to the tools used to manipulate them, but deployment to GoDaddy might be less well-received, and we don't take questions about installing SQL Server.

And, of course, we don't generally accept product recommendation questions of any kind, or requests for lists of things.

Comment: Might want to check out this new social network for asking questions - www.Formvote.com - pretty good.